# how to delete 3days old back files automatically in server and My backup files looks like?

Tags: linux, database, shell, cron

web_20_10_2022
web_21_10_2022
web_22_10_2022
web_23_10_2022
web_24_10_2022
web_25_10_2022
I need auto delete script for 3 days old backup files from server and with cron job.

below are some commond I have tried but it is not working, so please help me out!!!

find /home -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -rf {} +

find /home* -mtime +3 -type f -delete

find /home -mtime +3 -type d -exec rmdir {} ;

Comment: " it is not working" you need to provide details about what's not working.  No successful computer user debugs behavior without looking at results.  All those commands are going to delete everything over 3 days old in all of `/home` - this is almost certainly a bad idea

Comment: all my backups store /home folder, I run this commends 5days old file's also there but not files delete.
ex: inside my backup folder lot of subdirectory there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run the below command to find out the files older than 3 days.

```
find /path/to/directory/* -mtime +3 -print
```

The older files will be displayed in the mentioned directory if the above command is used.

To delete the 3 day old files:

```
find /path/to/directory/* -type f -mtime +3 | xargs rm -f
```

or

```
find /path/to/directory/* -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

or

```
find /path/to/directory/* -type f -mtime +3 -delete
```

To automate the process:

Copy the below code and save the file in a directory where you are not performing any housekeeping activity.

```
#!/bin/bash
 
find /path/to/directory/* -mtime +3 -delete
```

Make the file an executable file and set a cron job.

```
crontab -e
```

To run the script at every hour, enter

```
00 * * * * /path/to/executablefile
```

Comment: find /home/* -mtime +3 -print  ==> inside home directory all backup file there but am not get any file's

Comment: https://snipboard.io/69WNhS.jpg    ===> see screenshot , old file's i manually removed.

Comment: From the screenshot, I can see those are all not older than 3 days. If you want to delete those files that are Oct 27 & 28 then try to run this command to print it.

find /path/to/directory/* -mtime +1 -print


For deletion, You can use the below command. 

find /path/to/directory/* -mtime +1 -delete

Comment: You never want to `find... | xargs rm -f` instead do `find... -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f`